# Creating a Link to a Windows Folder

Tags: python, windows

I am working on organizing a folder on my Windows computer. I want to write some Python code to create links inside a new folder which will allow the user to click the created links and it will take the user to the original folder.

So, for example,
say this is Folder 1:
asparagus
bananas
carrots
oranges
pineapples

and this is the new folder which I want to create links to Folder 1:
fruits
vegetables

Is this doable in Python?

I have been looking into detail about using the recursion function in Python.

Also, the folders I displayed above are extremely simple. My actual folders are full of files and additional files so keep that in mind. This is why I think recursion might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [symlink](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_symlink.htm):

```
os.symlink(src, dst)
```

Here is an example from this link:

```
import os

src = '/usr/bin/python'
dst = '/tmp/python'

# This creates a symbolic link on python in tmp directory
os.symlink(src, dst)

print "symlink created"
```

**Example:**

Assume you have folder `D:/Folder1` where is folder `D:/Folder1/oranges` and if you want to create symlink of this folder in `D:/Fruits` you should do that:

```
import os
os.symlink('D:/Folder1/oranges', 'D:/Fruits/oranges')
```

Comment: please explain clearly where and why you see the need of using recursion

Comment: I am going to be honest with you, it was a suggestion from a friend so that's the only reason I was considering it. I am very new to programming and just trying to dive into it and learn it.

Comment: to be honest I don't understand well what are you trying to achieve, but I  updated my answer with a simple example. I hope it somehow helps you

Comment: `os.symlink` is available for Windows in Python 3.2+. It's not available in Python 2, but you can use ctypes to call `CreateSymbolicLinkW`. In either case, creating symlinks in Windows requires SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege, which is normally granted only to elevated administrators. Python 3.8+ will support creating symlinks without this privilege if and only if the system is in developer mode. Otherwise if you want standard users to have this privilege, use secpol.msc to grant it to the "Authenticated Users" group, to which all users logged on with credentials belong.